# Back Face Culling operation in Java

Tags: java

Is there any URL that explains Back Face Culling operation in Java?

Comment: Are we talking about 3D graphics? You have to be more specific. You could be talking about back-face culling, occlusion culling, viewing frustum culling, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first result in google is: [How to use Back Face Culling](http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/java3d/how-to-use-back-face-culling.html)

Comment: and here are many others: http://www.google.com/search?q=Back%20Face%20Culling%20operation%20in%20Java

Answer (score 2):

Here's a URL:
http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/java3d/how-to-use-back-face-culling.html

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found two links. These are best ones.

http://www.garybeene.com/3d/3d-java.htm

http://www.garybeene.com/3d/3d-view.htm